# Connect to an existing Azure Container Instance ACI from Azure ML

Tags: azure-container-instances, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an active Azure container Instance which is running, How can I add it to my Workspace using the Azure ML SDK.

Comment: quick question, since api are simply to recreate, what is the rational in trying to import your act model into your workspace ?

Comment: The ACI has been add to a vnet by admins. So I need to deploy my machine learning model on it. To do this I need to add it to the machine learning workspace.

Comment: from the looks at the SDK, the Model.deploy function expect to create the ACI for you, I couldn't see any way to load/import a model object from an existing ACI.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I don't get any response. Do you still work this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes @djsly is right. There is no way to load or import from an existing ACI

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you misunderstand the ML. As I know it's just a way to deploy the docker image into ACI (if you want to deploy ACI). And when you finish deploying, then the ACI is already a resource and has no relationship with the ML. It's no difference when the ACI is created. So there is no need to add the ACI to the ML workspace when it's running.